# Sensitive Cookie in HTTPS Session Without 'Secure' Attribute

Tags: javascript

I am setting some values in cookie through JS in my code. I am passing secure; while setting values to cookie. But still I am getting "Sensitive Cookie in HTTPS Session Without 'Secure' Attribute" as vulnerability.

```
document.cookie=`${name}=${val1};domain=${domainName};path=/;secure;`;
```

Comment: perhaps that refers to cookies received from the server

Comment: recommend you check your cookies in developer tools - then you should find the culprit

Comment: try `httpOnly` flag with `secure`

Comment: Which tool is reporting the vulnerability? Where and how?

Comment: have you tried to contact the developer of whatever tool you were using? also, make sure the cookie in question was the one set by your presented code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps make sure that the vulnerability detection tool you're using is updated and accurate? It's possible that the tool is generating a false positive or not properly detecting the "secure" attribute in your code for some reason.

Maybe true using a different vulnerability detection tool, though I'm not sure whether that would work.

I'd comment this, but I don't have the reputation to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're setting the secure flag while setting the cookie, which is the correct way to make sure the cookie is only ever sent over HTTPS. However, it's possible that the vulnerability scanner is flagging it as a false positive anyways.

You could try explicitly setting the HttpOnly flag as well. It ensures that the cookie cannot be accessed by client-side scripts. You can add it to the cookie like this:

```
document.cookie=`${name}=${val1};domain=${domainName};path=/;secure;HttpOnly`;
```